# Where does the name AVRO come from?

Tags: avro

I have an obsession with knowing what acronyms mean, especially in the IT field. It also forces me to understand every new acronym. So I gain insight with new technologies.

But I couldn't find a meaning to AVRO.

Ok, `A` in AVRO most likely comes from `Apache` and I guess `O` is short for `Object`.

So what do `V` and `R` short for? Let's say `V` is for version. So what about `R`?

**A**pache **V**ersioned **R**obust **O**bject?

Comment: From the wiki page: The Apache Avro logo is from the defunct British aircraft manufacturer Avro (originally A.V. Roe and Company)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: The name of a technology has a lot to do with its function and meaning. Otherwise we would be naming all of our variables as a,b,c,...etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm. Avro (as in Apache Avro) is a name, not an acronym. The logo for Apache Avro was derived from the  British aircraft manufacturer Avro (originally A.V. Roe), that's surely the origin of the name as well.

Comment: So is there a history of this? Why did they pick the British aircraft manufacturer Avro?

Comment: Stackoverflow can't answer that; only the people who picked it can tell you why they picked it. This whole question is off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Google is your friend...